# GTK creating new simple widget

Tags: c, gtk, widget

how can I achieve a widget like that:
Image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/widget.jpg/

I don't want to use gtk_vbox + 2x gtk_hbox every time. I would like to create it by doing simple:
`my_widget_new()` and then be able to change labels by doing something like:   `my_widget_label1(const char* text);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GtkTable Widget to do this.

If you want to create your own layout widget you have to dig through the source code of GtkBox which is the simplest of all layout widgets. While i have seen tutorials for normal widgets (well to be honest it's only always the same one - the clock widget) i have never found one that explains layout widgets.